# Is it right to throw exceptions from sided packages?

Tags: java, exception, readability

I want to throw an exception with certain name and such exception is already exists in sided packege.

E.g. `UnexpectedException` in `java.rmi`. I don't use any facilities from rmi packege, but the name of exception is *exactly* what I need.

I can either throw that exception in my own context or create a new exception with the same name. Which way is better?

Comment: Create your own with same name and use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just because the *name* is right doesn't mean anything else is. Look at the description, for example:

> An UnexpectedException is thrown if the client of a remote method call receives, as a result of the call, a checked exception that is not among the checked exception types declared in the throws clause of the method in the remote interface.

Does that *actually* describe what your exception is trying to represent? I suspect not.

Imagine you were a client - you would wonder why on earth you had to *catch* (or declare) something to do with RMI, despite none of your codebase being relevant to RMI. The oddity would spread throughout the code. Ick.

Answer (score 3):

When you look at the fully qualified name of the Exception, `java.rmi` is part of its name. Consider a programmer using your code reading to expect an exception from `java.rmi`, which will likely raise an eyebrow and hence be a bad idea.

Considering this exception in particular: *what* is unexpected? You could name your class `UnexpectedSomethingException` instead, making it clearer what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

[@Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15390137/451518) and [@akaIDIOT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15390153/451518) already provided pretty good answers. I'll just add a couple of examples relevant to your question:

- [UnexpectedException](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/1.1/play/exceptions/UnexpectedException.html) from Play! Framework
- [UnexpectedException](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/server/UnexpectedException.html) from Google Web Toolkit

It would be weird and confusing to handle `java.rmi.UnexpectedException` from the method that has nothing to do with RMI.

Also note that the main purpose of exceptions is to allow client code to handle the situation you couldn't handle yourself. So the fact that method throws `java.io.IOException` implies that client code should take a responsibility of handling unexpected file input-output errors (recheck file access/existance, basic settings). Method throwing `java.rmi.UnexpectedException` gives a hint to client code to check RMI settings

Comment: I've updated my answer, thanks. I'm happy that I didn't used comma instead of `and`. That would be embarassing.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend NOT reusing another exception just based on the fact that it shares the name you want.  For example, throwing a java.rmi.UnexpectedException outside of the context of RMI would be very confusing.

I'm not sure exactly how you intend on using your exception but to me, based solely on the name, that sounds like you could just use java.lang.RuntimeException, since it has the same general meaning.

So my recommendations would be in this order:

1. Use RuntimeException if it truly is an unexpected expected exception that your code is not prepared to handle. This is most approriate if you don't really need any new functionality than RuntimeException already provides.
2. Create your own custom UnexpectedException class. There's really no reason to strictly avoid using a certain class name just because some other library already uses it.  That's one of the points of packages - to provide a namespace to disambiguate same names.  With modern IDE's, there's really no reason for concern. Other may disagree - this is a matter of taste - but I personally don't see an issue with it.  There's certainly no technical reason not to do it.